# Redux React implementation error

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-redux

Hi in my case solutions here won't work My code:

**index.js**

```
import App from './App';

let store = createStore(App);

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" name='Strona główna' component={App}>
                <IndexRoute name='' component={Welcome}/>
                <Route name='Dashboard' path="dashboard" component={ReatEstateList}/>
```

Error apeares in **App.js** after imports

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

Comment: It's mean to be a class or function?

Comment: Should be `render() {`

Comment: @Morpheus What if it's a function, not a class?

Comment: @Kind user what are you referring to?

Comment: @Morpheus If it's a func -> `ReactDOM.render(...)`

Comment: @Kinduser I am with you now. Shouldn't it be `ReactDOM.render(...)`? :)

Comment: import {render} from 'react-dom'; and using that we could call for render() @Morpheus nope that solution is bad -> render() {

Comment: Using render() we declare it like import method from Class then I could use only render but its not a function then render(){} is bad